# Hopw to make a multiple anchor regex query against an index in mongo

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I'm searching indexes using regular expression anchors like so:

```
/^[Anchor1]/
```

and it's all well and good.  It matches all values that start with "Anchor1" and it uses the idex to do so.

However, I want to match one of a number of start strings, like so:

```
/^[Anchor1][Anchor2][Anchor3][Anchor4]/
```

It's so slow it's not returning.  This is for any case where there are more than 3 Anchors.  I'm fairly certain it's something simple. Either my regular expression is crap (I expect this miught be the case - I hate regular expressions) or my mongo-fu is weak.  I'm using the Java driver if that's relevant.

**My question is:**

What am I doing wrong here?  I'd like to be able to utilise a mongo index to match one of several possible start strings.

**Update**

doh.  My regular expression was rubbish.  It should be (thanks Sammaye):

```
^(Anchor1|Anchor2|Anchor3)
```

It's still really slow though.  I'll open a clearer question.

Comment: Can you show us some sample input ? I am really confused that your regular expression matches anything useful ?

Comment: Hang on, I think it's my regex that's broken here.

Comment: I've updated the question to make more sense.

Comment: You need to use the regex or operator like so `/^(d|s|r)/` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are still not making a lot of sense because `^[Anchor]` doesn't match `Anchor` at the start of string, it rather matches any `A`, `n`, `,c`, `h`, `o` or `r` at the start of string, and this is happening because you are using a character class `[]`.

To match an anchor named `Anchor` at the start-of-string you need to use:

```
^Anchor
```

You don't need any character classes for this.

If there are multiple anchors then you can do this:

```
^(?:Anchor|Anchor1|Anchor2|...|AnchorN)
```

This can't be optimized further unless you told us what are the exact anchors you are trying to match.

Comment: What does the ?: do ?

Comment: @tom `(?:)` This is called a non-capturing group. It can make the regular expression a bit faster. You can use it when you don't need the luxury of capturing groups `()` which save any value they match into memory so you can reference it later in the regular expression itself or in the program after the regular expression match

Comment: @tom You are very welcome, check [RegularExpressions.info](http://www.regularexpressions.info.com) for more info.